Executable runs locally but has oracle exception when running remotely
I have a C# console application that runs fine if executed locally, however when trying to remotely execute, my logger (Nlog) logs an Oracle exception. Specifically it's: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
This is my PowerShell script to invoke the application remotely:
# Define the remote server's hostname or IP address
$remoteServer = "Computer"

# Define the credentials to use for logging into the remote server
$username = "Username"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password

# Define the path to the .NET program you want to execute on the remote server
$programPath = "D:\Application\ABD\ABD.exe"

# Define parameters to pass to the .NET program
$parameters = "-s1"

# Use Invoke-Command to execute the program on the remote server
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteServer -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock {
    param($programPath, $parameters)
    
    # Execute the .NET program with parameters and capture the exit status
    $exitCode = & $programPath $parameters

    # Return the exit status
    return $exitCode
} -ArgumentList $programPath, $parameters

# Output the exit status returned by the .NET program
Write-Output "Exit Status: $result"

I was getting this error locally as well but after installing Oracle Client on the host computer, the application runs fine locally.
My question is why would I not be able to run the application without an Oracle Exception remotely, if it runs fine locally?
Update I switched the TNS_ADMIN environment variable to the host computer instead of a shared location and I got it to run. I'm guessing I have to pass the environment variable in the PowerShell script.

When I run it directly on the remote server it's fine. I run it through command line cd to the directory. I have TNS_ADMIN, ORACLE_BASE, and ORACLE_HOME environment variables set on the remote server

Are those variables being set for the remote execution? Or does something rely on having cd'd to the directory? (e.g. TNS_ADMIN pointing to the current directory, say.) The error suggests TNS_ADMIN is not set or is wrong or relative to something that isn't the same. Maybe you can add debugs to the application to print the value of that on startup, before it tries to connect to the database?

TNS_ADMIN is set to a company network location. I don't think anything else is dependent on cd'ing to the .EXE directory because I have the same issue if I do a PSSession to the remote machine and cd to the directory, the application still fails with the same TNS error. I will have to add debugs as you suggest.

Does that means it's on a network share - and that isn't defined when you access the server that way?

The TNS_ADMIN does point to a network share. Without too much experience, I'm assuming since the TNS_ADMIN is set on the remote server, it would use that when it gets invoked remotely, but I guess that's not the case?

Yes, but if the share itself isn't defined then the path the TNS_ADMIN points to won't be found, it won't find the tnsnames.ora, and you'll get that error. It may be defined during a normal login process, but not with the remote access?

What do you mean defined? The network path is accessible from all computers involved.   Should something be passed in the PowerShell script to the remote server?

Maybe you're seeing something like this, with the access to the share not being authenticated. I don't know much about PowerShell though, so there may be more recent and helpful answers or documentation. Hopefully someone with PowerShell experience will be able to give more guidance.

Which provider do you use at your application? ODP.NET Managed Driver?

Yes OracleManagedDataAccess.dll
